# How to access script-variable in mapping?

Tags: vim

I want to do following behaviour

```
let s:cmd = “echo ‘here is a long command’”

map aa :execute s:cmd<cr>
“ error, mapping cannot access script variable 

map bb :execute <SID>cmd<cr>
“ error no variable named <SNR>…cmd
```

How to access the script variable in mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a script local function and then access to the variable through that function.

```
let s:var = 'foo'

function! s:get(key) abort
  return get(s:, a:key)
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> µ :<c-u>echo <sid>get('var')<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I am finding a naturally  feature , but this is an alternative solution.